# How can I switch off autosave in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

Whenever I run a script in Spyder, it automatically saves my file. How can I prevent this from happening?. I had an older version that never done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `Save all files before running script` in the preferences. You will need to go to `Preferences > Editor > Run code` and uncheck the option:

[image]